# wp_is_mobile() inside js

Tags: menus, admin, wp-admin, admin-menu, admin-css

I've stumbled upon a issue that i can't fix.

I've implemented a autocollapse menu ..all works fine UNTILL i go to mobile version where the wp core's menu bugs out with my menu js code.

Basicly i have a js file that contains the auto-collapse menu code and would like to run this bit

```
$('#adminmenuwrap, #adminmenuback').mouseenter(function() { expandIt($adminMenuWrap); }); 
    $('#wpcontent , .box').mouseenter(function() { collapseIt($adminMenuWrap); });
    $('img').load(function($){collapseIt($adminMenuWrap);});      
    });
```

ONLY if you are NOT in mobile version.

fiddled around with if (wp_is_mobile() ) {} function but doesn't work.

Please guys help me fix this cuz it's giving me headakes.
Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Entire JS file :

```
    /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */

// MyDash Collapse Menu
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Defineste functii
    $adminMenuWrap = $('#adminmenuwrap');
    var collapseIt = function($adminMenuWrap) {
        if ( !$(document.body).hasClass('folded') ) {
            $("#collapse-menu").trigger('click');
            $(document.body).toggleClass('expanded');
        }
    };

    var expandIt = function($adminMenuWrap) {
        adminMenuWrap = $('#adminmenuwrap');
        if ( $(document.body).hasClass('folded') ) {
            $("#collapse-menu").trigger('click');
            $(document.body).toggleClass('expanded');
        }
    }




     if ($(window).width() > 768){
    // here's the magic
    $('#adminmenuwrap, #adminmenuback').mouseenter(function() { expandIt($adminMenuWrap); }); 
    $('#wpcontent , .box').mouseenter(function() { collapseIt($adminMenuWrap); });
    $('img').load(function($){collapseIt($adminMenuWrap);});      
    });    
     }


// Customizer
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".boxes").mouseenter(function() {
        if ( $('.wp-full-overlay').hasClass('collapsed') ) {
            $(".collapse-sidebar").trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $("#customize-preview").mouseover(function() {
        if ( $('.wp-full-overlay').hasClass('expanded') ) {
            $(".collapse-sidebar").trigger('click');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: explain what doesn't work and what append, what is shown

Comment: You could just try `if ($(window).width() < 768) ` to detemine if you want to run the code

Comment: @mmm it simply stops autocollapsing without any error

Comment: @czerspalace still no result

Comment: Are your braces matched up correctly? What if you move the width check inside the `mouseenter` functions (and 768 was just an arbitrary number, you may need to change that)

Comment: was that it needed to be in the mouseenter function after all ..giii dude..thanks a lot :D

Comment: Where is your javascript located? As mentioned in @mmm answer, are you sure the JS is loading?